# Find $x$ such that $x^{677} ≡ 3 \mod 2020$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have been reviewing number theory questions and there is one problem I am stuck on.

Find $x$ such that $x^{677} ≡ 3 \mod 2020$.

My approach was to start by applying Euler’s Theorem. I know that $\phi(2020) = 800$, but I don’t know if this is very useful... How should I proceed?

Comment: Since $2020=2^2\times 5\times 101$ you can solve the problem mod $4,5,101$ separately and then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: [The answer is $x\equiv 1\pmod {2020}$](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EIzpTIS2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw8jAyEBTITNNoSC/XCNTx8zMXAcsZGtrGKv5/z8A) if that helps

Comment: "The answer is x≡1(mod2020) if that helps"  As $1^{677}\not \equiv 3 \pmod{2020}$ that obviously isn't correct.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin:  we want $x^{6\color{red}77}\equiv\color{red}3$, not $x^{667}\equiv1$

Comment: Solvable by exactly the same methods described in the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment by [lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu), $2020=2^2\times5\times101$,

so solve the problem mod $4,5,$ and $101$ separately,

and then use the Chinese remainder theorem.

I.e., $x\equiv3\bmod4$ , $x\equiv3\bmod 5$, and $x^{77}\equiv3\bmod101$.

$77\times13=1001\equiv1\bmod100$, so $x\equiv3^{13}\equiv38\bmod101$.

So we have $x\equiv3\bmod20$ and $x\equiv38\bmod101$.

Can you now show $x\equiv543\bmod2020$?

Comment: If it were $x^{6\color{red}67}\equiv3$, then we'd have $x\equiv3\bmod4, x\equiv3^3\bmod5, $ and $x\equiv3^3\bmod101$, so some arithmetic would be easier